# kinetic js saving canvas stage

Tags: javascript, html, kineticjs

Im still learning kinecticjs and was wondering how you can save the state of the cavas?

from:
http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-save-stage-as-json-string-with-kineticjs/

```
      // save stage as a json string
      var json = stage.toJSON();

      console.log(json);
```

But how do i load this back in? Thanks

Comment: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-load-stage-with-json-string-with-kineticjs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a tutorial [here](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-load-stage-with-json-string-with-kineticjs/) for loading stage from a JSON String.
You just have to do :

```
var json = '{"attrs":{"width":578,"height":200},"className":"Stage","children":[{"attrs":{},"className":"Layer","children":[{"attrs":{"x":289,"y":100,"sides":6,"radius":70,"fill":"red","stroke":"black","strokeWidth":4},"className":"RegularPolygon"}]}]}';

// create node using json string
var stage = Kinetic.Node.create(json, 'container');
```

Hope that answers the question.

Answer (score 1):

Each object references its class name in the property `className`. Therefore, it should be as simple as iterating through the JSON object and doing something like

```
var obj = new Kinetic[node.className](node.attrs);
```

Use `JSON.parse()` to convert the string into an usable object.

Comment: That sounds very complicated, is there no easier way? or an example i can follow?

Comment: @fuzzy If there is an easier way, I do not know of it.